# One tailed confidence interval $1 - 2\alpha $ rationale

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

In my statistics textbook, I’ve noticed a pattern that is clear but the rationale for which isn’t explained:

When constructing a one tailed confidence interval, the confidence level is equal to $ 1 - 2\alpha $. I can apply this idea, but can someone please explain to me the rationale? Why is $ 1 - 2\alpha $ the confidence level for a one tailed test when a two tailed test is $1 - \alpha $?

I should add that my understanding is that a one tailed confidence interval should have confidence level equal to $1 - \alpha $ because each tail in a two tailed confidence interval has area $1 - \alpha/2 $. This is what I cannot reconcile.

Edit: This table is referenced repeatedly in the book but no justification I can find is given. The book is “Essentials of Statistics,” 5th edition, Triola, Mario F.
[image: Confidence Interval]

Edit: I’ve included some reference photos from two sections of the book. The first two photos below are from a general section on confidence intervals where only two tailed intervals are discussed. [image: critical value 1]

[image: critical value 2]

The following two photos are from a section on chi-squares tests. I can not reconcile the statements regarding confidence level in the next photo from the statement about alpha in the final photo:

[image: chi 1]
[image: chi 2]

Comment: "Why is $ 1 - 2\alpha $ the confidence level for a one tailed test" In which book do you have read this statement?

Comment: @callculus I’ll edit the question to include a photo of a table in the book. I may have misinterpreted it, because the rationale is not explained anywhere in the book. I’ll include a citation of book name too, although I don’t want to malign an author for something that is most likely my mistake.

Comment: It is true what you have written. I´m not sure if the the book is right. We will see what are the statements from other users here.

Comment: For me it doesn´t seem very logical.

Comment: @callculus I’ve added to this question to clarify my understanding of the area in each tail of a two tailed confidence interval. My assumption then, is that the confidence level for a one-tailed confidence interval should be $1 - \alpha $.

Comment: @callculus I am not able to update the post until later, but I have found a passage in the book that seems to contradict this table (although, I’m sure I must be misinterpreting it). I’ll update this evening.

Comment: I’ve added some more information from the book; I’d be curious to see your interpretation. It seems the books is very deliberate in what it states, so I must be misunderstanding the meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we have to be clear on the definition of $\alpha.$ That may be the
nub of your problem. So I will talk about 95% confidence intervals (CIs).

**Two sided CIs:**

***95% t CI for normal mean $\mu,$ with $\sigma$ unknown.***
Suppose we seek a CI for unknown normal population mean $\mu$
given $n$ observations. Suppose population SD $\sigma$ is also unknown and estimated by sample SD $S.$ Then
$$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu = n-1),$$

If $n = 20,$ then 'degrees of freedom' $\nu = 20-1= 19$ and the numbers $\pm 2.093$
cut 2.5% from the upper and lower tails of the (symmetrical) distribution
$\mathsf{T}(\nu = 19).$ These 'cut-off' values can be obtained in R statistical software using the quantile function (inverse CDF) of $\mathsf{T}(19).$
Look at a printed t table in your text to see how you can get the number 2.393 
from a printed table: the row is $\nu = 19$ the column may be labeled
something like $t_{.025}$.

> *Note:* The number 2.3093 is *quantile* 0.975 of $\mathsf{T}(19),$ also called the *percentage point* 0.025 of this distribution.
>   Notice that *quantiles* focus on probability *below* and *percentage points* focus on probability *above.* In a, possibly misguided, attempt to help with confidence intervals and hypothesis tests, the t table in your book may
>   have a different label.

```
qt(.975, 19);  qt(.025, 19)
[1] 2.093024   # cuts 2.5% from upper tail of T(19)
[1] -2.093024  # cuts 2.5% from lower tail of T(19)
```

Now we know that $P(-2.093 < T < 2.093) = 0.95.$ With some algebra using
the definition of $T$ above, this probability can be rewritten as
$$ P\left(\bar X - 2.093\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}} < \mu < \bar X + 2.093\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 0.95.$$

Based on this, we say that a (two-sided) 95% CI for $\mu$ is of the form

$$ \left(\bar X - 2.093\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},\: \bar X + 2.093\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

[image]

***$95\%\; \chi^2$ CI for normal variance $\sigma^2,$ with $\mu$ unknown.***
Suppose we seek a 95% CI for unknown normal population variance $\sigma^2$ given $n = 20$ observations. Suppose population mean $\mu$ is also unknown and estimated by the sample mean $\bar X.$ Then

$$ Q = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$$

Then the numbers $L=8.907$ and $U=32.852$ cut 2.5% of the probability from the lower
and upper tails respectively of the (asymmetrical) distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ These 'cut-off' values can be obtained in R statistical software
using the quantile function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ Look at a printed
chi-squared table in your test to see how you can get the numbers $L=8.907$ and $U=32.852$ from row $\nu = n-1=19).$

```
qchisq(.975, 19);  qchisq(.025, 19)
[1] 32.85233  # U cuts 2.5% from upper tail of CHISQ(20)
[1] 8.906516  # L cuts 2.5% from lower tail of CHISQ(20)
```

Now we know that $P(8.907 < Q < 32.852) = 0.95.$ Based on this we can show that a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is of the form
$$\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U}.\; \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right)
= (19S^2/32.852,\; 19S^2/8.907).$$
If you want a 95% CI for the population standard deviation $\sigma,$ then
simply take square roots of the above CI for $\sigma^2.$

[image]

***Duality between two-sided CIs and two-sided hypothesis tests.***
Suppose you have $n = 20$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$
where both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown. Then

(a) If you have a 95% CI for $\mu$ of the form $\bar X \pm 2.093/\sqrt{20},$
and you want to test $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against $H_a: \mu \ne \mu_0,$ then
you will reject $H_0$ at significance level 5%, if the hypothetical population mean $\mu_0$ does *not* lie in the CI. This is the same as saying to reject $H_0$ if $|T| > 2.0935,$ where the test statistic $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{20}}.$ One says that $c = 2.093$ is the 'critical value' of the two-sided test; then it is understood that the absolute value of the test statistic is used.
(Some authors say that $\pm c$ are critical value***s*** of the test).

(b) Suppose you have a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ of the form $(19S^2/32.852,\; 19S^2/8.907),$ and you want to test $H_0: \sigma^2 = \sigma_0^2$ against
$H_a: \sigma^2 \ne \sigma_0^2.$ Then you will reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance, if the test statistic $Q$ does not lie in the CI. This is the same as rejecting when $Q$ is outside the interval $(8.0935, 32.852),$ where $Q = (n-1)S^2/\sigma_0^2.$ One says that $L=8.0935$ and $U=32.852$ are the lower and upper
values of the two-sided test.

***Why might you want to have a CI along with results of a test?***
Suppose you have a process that is supposed to produce items with normally distributed values averaging $\mu_0 = 100$
units. Either too high or too low is not not good. You sample $n = 25$ items, obtaining $\bar Y =93.49$ and $S = 14.36.$

You notice that $\bar Y$ is somewhat below $\mu_0 = 100.$ Is that *significantly* below in a statistical sense? Testing $H_0: \mu = 100$ against $H_a: \mu \ne 100$ at the 5% level, you have critical values $c = \pm 2.145.$ But
$T = -2.266,$  so that $|T| = 2.266 > 2.145.$ You reject $H_0,$ concluding
that $\bar Y$ differs significantly from the desired $\mu_0 = 100.$ 
How far might the true mean $\mu$ be from 100?

A 95% CI for $\mu$ is $(87.56, 99.42),$ and engineers say that includes values disappointingly far from $\mu_0 = 100,$ so we should try to refine the production process.

```
set.seed(629);  y = rnorm(25, 95, 15)  # fake data generated with pop mean 95
t.test(y, mu = 100, conf.lev = .95)

        One Sample t-test

data:  y
t = -2.2664, df = 24, p-value = 0.03272
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 100
95 percent confidence interval:
 87.56435 99.41852
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 93.49143 
sd(y)
[1] 14.35895
qt(.975, 24)
[1] 2.144787
```

---

**One-Sided CIs:**

***95% lower bound for $\mu,$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are unknown***
Suppose we have $n$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ with both parameters unknown, where $\bar X$ and $S$ are the sample mean and standard deviation, respectively. We want a 95% one-sided (lower-bounded) CI for $\mu.$

(a) *Derivation using a trick:* Presumably fearing that some students would find a straightforward derivation of a one-sided CI counterintuitive, Triola uses the following 'trick': Artificially double the error rate to get a 90% CI as above. [There's your unexplained $1 - 2\alpha.]$ Because the numbers $\pm 1.729$ cut 5% from the two tails of $\mathsf{T}(19)$ the 90% CI is $\bar X \pm 1.729S/\sqrt{n}$ or $(\bar X - 1.729S/\sqrt{n},\, \bar X + 1.729S/\sqrt{n}).$

Then the argument seems to be that half of the error must be beyond each end of this CI, so
a one-sided 95% CI must be $(\bar X - 1.729S/\sqrt{n},\, \infty)$ and the lower bound is $\bar X - 1.729S/\sqrt{n}.$

(b) *The straightforward derivation:*
We have $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim 
\mathsf{T}(\nu = n-1),$ where we denote the standard error as $E = S/\sqrt{n}.$ 
For $n = 20$  can find $U = 1.729$ such that

$$0.95 = P(T < U) = P((\bar X - \mu)/E < U) = P(\bar X - \mu < UE)\\ 
= P(\mu - \bar X  > -UE) = P(\mu > \bar X - UE).$$

Thus a one-sided CI for $\mu$ is of the form $(\bar X - UE,\, \infty)$, with lower bound $\bar X - US/\sqrt{n}$ for $\mu.$ For $n = 20,$ the lower bound is $1.729S/\sqrt{20}.$

***A one-sided confidence interval with a one-sided test.***
A large software company selects $n = 15$ programmers to see how much time they spend each day on activities not directly related to programming (mandatory seminars, personnel activities, breaks, and so on). While it is not expected that programmers spend 8 hours a day 'programming', company guidelines specify that the non-programming time should not be more than 2.5 hours a day.

The sample mean is $\bar W = 2.93$ and the sample SD is $S = 0.553.$ Testing $H_0: \mu \le 2.5$ against $H_a: \mu > 2.5$ at level $\alpha = 0.05,$ you obtain $T = 3.04,$ which exceeds the one-sided critical value $c = 1.761.$ So it is unlikely that $W = 2.93$ is significantly greater than the target maximum $\mu_0 = 2.5.$

The one-sided 95% CI for $\mu$ sets a lower bound beneath we are 'confident' $\mu$ does not fall. The CI is $(2.68, \infty),$ so it seems likely that the true value of $\mu > 2.86.$

```
set.seed(630);  w = rnorm(15, 2.8, .6)
t.test(w, mu=2.5, alte="gr", conf.lev=.95)

        One Sample t-test

data:  w
t = 3.0401, df = 14, p-value = 0.004411
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 2.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.682506      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 2.933875 

summary(w);  sd(w);  qt(.95, 14)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.792   2.783   3.048   2.934   3.303   3.784 
[1] 0.5527393  # sample SD
[1] 1.76131    # critical value
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I want to give it my full concentration to be sure I understand and can answer you, so I will spend some time with it this evening when I return home.

Comment: I think (or thought) I understood CI’s for two sided tests well enough; I understood $ \alpha $ to be the probability of making a type I error. That is to say a 95% CI for a two sided test would have $ \alpha = 0.05 $. So the confidence level for a two sided test would be $ 1 - \alpha $, and the area in each tail of a two sided CI would be $ \alpha  /  2 $. I am walking my dogs as I write so I may need to revisit your post when I’m home. I suppose my previous understanding was incorrect?

Comment: After focusing on your post, I believe I understand every line you have written. I also believe the confidence intervals have an error in the signs on the right hand side and should read: $$ \left (\bar X -2.093\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},\: \bar X + 2.093\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$ Thus far my understanding seems to have been correct but I can see I’ve misinterpreted the jump to one sided tests. However, YouTube seems to have agreed with my one sided understanding, but I’m not putting my faith in YouTube.

Comment: I didn’t mean that last comment to sound snarky about the change in signs. I just meant that if I am understanding correctly, I believe the signs would need to be switched. I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: Ok I believe I see where the book was misleading IMHO. All we are doing to compute a one sided confidence interval with 95% confidence level is computing a 2 sided interval with $\alpha = 0.10 $, then splitting that area as usual into two tails. Then we disregard the lower tail... So I believe the significance level is ACTUALLY still 95% in a one sided test, but it’s trying to say it would be equivalent to the critical value of a two sided test with 90% confidence level. This seems misleading to call it a confidence level of $ 1 - 2\alpha $ in table 8-1.

Comment: It’s trying to illustrate how to calculate a one sided test, but imho it looks to be saying the confidence level is actually $1 - 2\alpha $, when in reality the confidence level is still $1 - \alpha $.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typos (fixed now). Please just make sure you totally understand how the tables are used so far, the two-sided CIs and tests, and the 'duality' between CIs and tests. Making fine progress. // Let's leave the one-sample tests later (later tonight or tomorrow, I guess). Best to master one topic totally before going on to another somewhat similar one. Also, enough typing for now or I'll make even more typos.

Comment: OK. Finally done. Please let me know if you find more typos. // Possibly relevant fable: A rich friend of mine buys a huge chocolate chip cookie for \$5 every day at the cafe to go with his fancy coffee, but he eats only half of it. Someone asks why he doesn't get the half-size cookie for \$2.50. He says: "It's counterintuitive to break a \$5 bill." – BruceET 14 mins ago

Comment: I will spend time with this today as well. Wow, thank you. This should be a section in a textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Given the significance level $\alpha$, the confidence level must be the same $(1-\alpha)\cdot 100\%$ for both one-tailed and two-tailed hypothesis tests, but the critical values must differ. Here is an alternative table of the confidence levels:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
{\text{Sign.level}\\ \ \ \ \ \ \alpha} & {\text{Conf.coef}\\ \ \ \ \ 1-\alpha} & { \ \ \ \ \ \text{Conf.level}\\(1-\alpha)\cdot 100\%} & {\text{Crit.value}\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ z_{\alpha}} & {\text{Crit.value}\\ \ \ \ \ \ z_{\alpha/2}}\\
\hline
0.01 & 0.99 & 99\% & 2.33 & 2.575 \\
0.05 & 0.95 & 95\% & 1.64 & 1.96 \\
0.10 & 0.90 & 90\% & 1.28 & 1.64
\end{array}
$$
So, in the referenced "Confidence interval method" table the one-tailed confidence level $98\%$ (corresponding to $\alpha=0.01$) must be $99\%$. It   seems it tries to convert one-tailed test to a confidence interval (two-tailed test), which is not appropriate, because the confidence interval (corresponding to one-tailed test) will be one-sided (depending on the alternative hypothesis). See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257526/can-one-sided-confidence-intervals-have-95-coverage) for reference.